# MySql user eating CPU and finally CPU overload

Tags: mysql, performance

i am using vps server and when i type  top always i see code below

```
cpu | pid  | user  | command
2.2 | 3954 | mysql | /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/xxx.hostname.com.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/xxx.hostname.com.pid
```

i dont understand what is this? how can i reduce this value? this is running after restart and never stop.

Comment: Need some more info to figure out what is going on - I would dump the contents of SHOW PROCESSLIST in MySQL first to see if there are any queries sitting there chewing up CPU time. MySQL slow log (if configured) may also hold the answer to your CPU issue.

Comment: | 1605  | eximstats    | localhost | eximstats    | Sleep   | 4150 |       |                  |
| 12514 | leechprotect | localhost | leechprotect | Sleep   | 3281 |       |                  |
| 13303 | root         | localhost |              | Query   | 0    |       | show processlist |

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you are running the [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) (mysqld) database on your VPS.

In terms of the CPU overload, my guess is that something is running a CPU intensive query on it. You can take a look at the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) to see if there are any queries that are taking a while (i.e. eating up your CPU).

The log is usually in `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log`.

Comment: of course mysql running also i've optimised with mysql tuning but this process everytime live, is it neccessary?

Comment: LOL - okay, it wasn't at all obvious what you were asking. @shannonman seems to be on the right track for you.

Comment: FYI, I'd look at the mysql slow query log to see if there's anything there that might be causing your cpu problems.

Comment: i've checked, slow query log under 0.1% according to other queries also mysql-tuning says your slow query ratio is good.